# Apache Lucene (Java server) initialization problem

Tags: java, server, lucene, rpc

I am trying to initialize an Apache Lucene server that will act as a search engine and as a .pdf generator.

My server (`server.ini`) config looks like:

```
[Server]
IpAddress = 127.0.0.1
Port = 11112
IndexPath = /var/www/tmp
LogFile = /var/log/server.log
LogLevel = INFO

# number of CPU threads when indexing
NumThreads = 3
RamBufferSize = 512M
# max size of e.g. PDFs to be analyzed
IndexMaxFileSizeMB=5


[Client1]
ClientId = id
NicId = 0
```

When I'm running the `start` command:

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar server.jar server.ini start &`

I get the following error/warning even though the server it's starting and running after this, but something seems to be wrong:

```
12:13:39.607 [XML-RPC-0] ERROR org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcErrorLogger - Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.readLine(Connection.java:241) ~[server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.getRequestConfig(Connection.java:150) ~[server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:204) ~[server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68) ~[server.jar:?]
```

When running `status` this is `running`:

`sudo java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar server.jar server.ini status &`

I get:

`Running`

Can somebody see what's wrong with the above, I cannot get my head around it?
Thanks

Comment: Is the `lucene` tag relevant to the problem you are having? It looks more like maybe a configuration problem with [Apache XML-RPC](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/).

Comment: Also, what is in `server.jar`?

Comment: @andrewJames the `server.jar` came in the installation of this app I'm trying to configure and I cannot see the contents of it when `nano server.jar`. I'm trying to follow https://github.com/ILIAS-eLearning/ILIAS/tree/release_7/Services/WebServices/RPC/lib and https://docu.ilias.de/goto_docu_pg_8239_367.html .